# Populating a field based on another field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Continuing on my Vehicle Reservation System I've already started working on the reserve function itself and I'm stuck on how to populate the Driver Field as it is based on the Vehicle Field. There are two types of vehicles, office type which has an already dependent driver from previous functions, and then vendor type initially has no driver until the reservation function where you get to choose from a dropdown field. In my controller code, vendor types are linked with the DriverID of 0. I'm not exactly sure how to implement the if statement here is my code so far:

Controller:

```
 //RESERVE
    public ActionResult ReserveInitial()
    {

       ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "DriverLastName");
       ViewBag.VehicleID = new SelectList(db.Vehicles, "VehicleID", "VehicleMake");

        var checkVehicle = db.ReservedVehicleDetails.Count(x => x.VehicleID == 1);




        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReserveInitial(ReservationViewModel RV)
    {
        var repo = new ManagementRepository();
        var resini = new ReservedVehicleInitial
        {
            Id = RV.Id,
            BorrowerLastName = RV.BorrowerLastName,
            BorrowerFirstName = RV.BorrowerFirstName,
            VehicleID = RV.VehicleID,
            Reason = RV.Reason,
            ProjectID = RV.ProjectID,
            Location = RV.Location,
            DateReserved = RV.DateReserved,
            TimeStart = RV.TimeStart,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            UserID = RV.UserID,
            DriverID = RV.DriverID

        };

                    Driver driver = new Driver();
                    if (resini.DriverID == 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "DriverLastName" + ", " + "DriverFirstName");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
                        {
                            ViewBag.DriverID = driver.DriverID;
                        }
                    }

        using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
        { 
            repo.ReserveInitial(resini);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

View Model:

```
    public class ReservationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerLastName { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerFirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReserved { get; set; }
    public int? VehicleID { get; set; }
    public int? DriverID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleMake { get; set; }
    public  string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public string OdometerStart { get; set; }
    public string OdometerEnd { get; set; }
    public string Liters { get; set; }
    public string AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public string ORNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeStart { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeEnd { get; set; }
    //
    public string BorrowerFullName
    {
        get { return BorrowerLastName + ", " + BorrowerFirstName; }
        set { }
    }
    //
    public string DriverLastName { get; set; }
    public string DriverFirstName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
     <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group control-label">
                                        <label>
                                            Vehicle
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Vehicle">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("VehicleID", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "VehicleID" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group control-label">
                                        <label>
                                            Driver
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                <div id="Driver">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("DriverID", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DriverID" })                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi! Do I implement it the same way for dynamic lists? Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course..